# How do I change default settings for link sharing on OneDrive?

Tags: permissions, onedrive, sharing

I'm seeking to change my personal OneDrive default setting for shared links.
By default, it generates links with "Edit" permission and I have to change each time to "View" permission.

I found out that corporate onedrive with SharePoint allows this, but nothing about personal account settings.

I have to display video classes to students, but also make sure they don't have any extra permissions.

Thanks